# Circuit Python MQTT Exception Block

Tags: python, micropython, adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

I'm using the  [Adafruit Circuit Python MQTT library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_MiniMQTT) and am trying to catch the errors being generated.

```
   while True:
    try:
        # Poll the message queue
        mqtt_client.loop()
    except (ValueError, RuntimeError, MMQTTException) as e:
        print("Failed to get data, retrying\n", e)
      
        mqtt_client.reconnect()
        # continue
    time.sleep(1)
```

But this generates the following error:

> NameError: name 'MMQTTException' is not defined

Any ideas how I should properly catch this error?

The library has the following error class. I'm guessing it needs to be exposed somehow?

```
class MMQTTException(Exception):
    """MiniMQTT Exception class."""

    # pylint: disable=unnecessary-pass
    # pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did something like

```py
import adafruit_minimqtt.adafruit_minimqtt as MQTT
```

in order to be able to use `mqtt_client = MQTT.MQTT(...)`, then you need to refer to this other class similarly, as `MQTT.MMQTTException`.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Also adding "from adafruit_minimqtt.adafruit_minimqtt import MMQTTException" to the top of the file worked as well.